# Como obter um objeto do PHP em uma função ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Eu tenho o código abaixo que faz um verificação na minha controller e a mesma me retorna um count da minha requisição.

O que eu queria é que no sucess do meu Jquery ajax eu capturasse este valor para fazer algumas tratativas por javascript em meu código.

Estou usando o framework Laravel 5.2.

Segue o código da minha função no javascript e da função na controller.

Controller:

```
public function verificaCPF($cpf){
        $cpfvalidoeexistente;
        if(BussinessRoles\SSV::validacaoCPF($cpf)){
            $cpfvalidoeexistente = Aluno::where('cpf', $cpf)->count();
        }
        else{
            $cpfvalidoeexistente = 0;
        }
        echo $cpfvalidoeexistente;
    }
```

Função no javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/validacpf/'+cpf, 
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            msg('sucesso', 'O registro foi atualizado com sucesso!', '#resposta')            
        },
        error: function () {            
            msg('atencao', 'Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o registro!', '#resposta');
        }});
```

Antes que questionem a rota está funcionando certinho o que eu não consigo é obter o valor de retorno.

Comment: Qual o resultado que imprime no console ? Você já tentou acessar a rota manualmente para ver no que resulta ?

Comment: A rota retorna certinho, mas quando eu vou verificar o retorno no console está em branco!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `Laravel 5`, quando queremos retornar algo (Seja HTML ou seja `JSON`), devemos usar a função `response` ou `view`.

É necessário utilizar a palavra chave `return` também.

Então, ao invés de fazer:

```
echo $meuValor
```

Você deve fazer:

```
 return response()->json($meuValor);
```

Ou ainda:

```
return response($meuValor);
```

No segundo caso, o `Laravel` trata automaticamente o tipo passado para `response`, para decidir se vai retornar um `json` ou não.

É importante usar essa função, pois assim, o `Laravel`retornará corretamente o `header`de resposta contendo o `content-type: application/json`

Comment: Cara valeu pela ajuda meu muito certo aqui... eu sabia que era somente um detalhe que passou despercebido... hauhsauhasu